# Strange new Boolean javascript behavior

Tags: javascript

can any one explain me this behavior:

```
if (new Boolean(true)){            
    alert("1");
}else{
    alert("2");
}
```

must be alert "1", and the response is "1", but

```
if (new Boolean(false)){            
    alert("1");
}else{
    alert("2");
}
```

must be alert "2", but the response is "1". Why?,

For example:

```
if (false){            
    alert("1");
}else{
    alert("2");
}
```

Response "2", and

```
if (true){            
    alert("1");
}else{
    alert("2");
}
```

response "1", as we should expect....

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm - Not browser-specific, `new Boolean(false)` creates an object. All objects are truthy. So `if (new Boolean(false))` takes the truthy branch, just like `if (true)` or `if (new Date())` or ... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because objects in JavaScript are true-ish.
When creating a boolean using object creator, `new Boolean`, you create an object wrapping a boolean value.

You could also see it when doing

```js
const x = new Boolean(false);

console.log(typeof x)
```

The output will be `object`. That said, the value of `new Boolean(false)` is true-ish for the `if` statement.

Comment: This is covered by plenty of previous questions and answers.

Comment: ok @talRofe I understand and can try it.